# python command on terminal not working

Tags: command-line, 16.04, python

Same question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802455/python-command-on-terminal-not-working) but without a valid solution. The problem is that typing `python` in the terminal produces:

```
The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-minimal
 * python3
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

In fact, `$ which python` returns nothing. Additional information:

```
~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/fontana/bin:/home/fontana/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

By default `python` should point to python2.7 in /user/bin. If I type `python2.7`, python runs normally. How to restore the default behavior when typing `python` in the terminal?

EDIT: Potential source of the problem: I've recently installed python 3.4.6 (in /user/local/bin) using the following commands. Than I tried to reinstall python 3.4.6 since there was a problem with pip now fixed.

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Comment: The next question is then always: what did you do that might have caused this?

Comment: The answer is in the question: Reinstall python-minimal.

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: DO NOT change the system version of Python. You will break your system horribly. Change it back. If you must add a new version of python, then install it manually instead of using packages.

Comment: I'm not capable to restore the previous situation. My impression is that pointing python (when typed in the terminal) to /usr/bin/python2.7 should do the trick, but I don't know how (maybe using export PATH?).

Comment: You point python using an ordinary symlink - see `man ln`. However, that's merely one tusk of the elephant of damage perhaps lurking, waiting to be discovered at unfortunate times. If you lack the skill to undo the damage, then backup your data and reinstall...having learned a valuable lesson.

Comment: I have solved the problem using `sudo apt install python-minimal`

Comment: So exactly what Ubuntu mentioned as solution and user535733 said 15 hours earlier :-)

Comment: @user535733, Could u rewrite the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the problem with

```
sudo apt install python-minimal
```

as suggested in the warning message. I have decided to install `python-minimal` rather than `python3` since the latter was already working smoothly in the terminal.

Comment: it seems python-minimal is python 2.7. However, I would like to install python 3.X